# .NET Core - Handling Error FluentValidation in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net-core, fluentvalidation

As the title says. How do I handling an Error in FluentValidation when i'm using form post with AJAX / jQuery?

here's my js

```
function Create(controlId: any) {
    var control = $('#' + controlId);
    var controller = control.data('controller');
    var url = '/' + controller + '/Create';
    var serializeForm = control.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: serializeForm,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data && data.IsSuccess == true) {
                // do success
            }
            else if (data && data.IsSuccess == false) {
                // this one if there is error in my service
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // do error
        }
    });
}
```

and here's my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Create([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "Create")] TViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await service.CreateAsync(vm, 1);

        return Json(result);
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Is it possible to do that with my current code?

In my ServiceResult i have:

```
RecordId
IsSuccess
Message (this one is for error in the service)
```

And for my current Code, i can't handle if there is error in my FluentValidation because I'm only returning the code `View(vm)`

So is there any other way to handle that?

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you returning a `View()` for an action that is called with ajax?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane because i don't know how to do it. btw, thanks for your answer. right now i'm returning `Json(ModelState)` in my controller, and can get the value of the Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation here](https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet%60), for a normal MVC, you simply need to return `View(model)` if the model state fails. This code is generally used when the `ModelState` contains all the error messages. The following is how you can set up the same for ajax:

**On the server side**

Within the action, you can use `return BadRequest(ModelState)` instead of `return View(vm)` in your code. Note that for web APIs (ajax needs to access a web API), returning bad request (400) is the standard when the provided input is invalid. The `BadRequest(object)` function a http 400 error with bad request with, serializes `object` 
and returns it as JSON. Running `BadRequest(ModelState)`, tries to serialize `ModelState`. The model state is designed to return the collection of error messages when it is serialized.

**On the client side**

In your js code, you can check for a 400 response to verify if there is an error. You can use `console.log` to print the error in case of a 400. This will help you understand the format of the error response. **Note** As of .net core 2.2 (releasing December) this output format will change. If you do upgrade to 2.2 later, you will have to change your js code.